# check flag before pthread_cond_wait()

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, concurrency

```
bool flag=false;
pthread_mutex_t mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void function1()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    while(!flag)
    {
    //#2
        pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
}

void function2()
{
    flag=true;
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
}
```

Here's the situation. Two threads:thread1 and thread2 are running on function1 and function2 respectively.

thread1 stops at #2 because of a CPU schedule.

thread2 begins execution and changed the flag to true.

thread1 begins wait but it would wait forever.

How to avoid this situation when I want to notify other thread without locking the mutex.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more?? your purpose is not clear

Comment: You are invoking undefined behavior by accessing `flag` without synchronization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why you must lock the mutex when you update the predicate (`flag`).  There is no alternative.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
flag = true;
pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

(You can move the `pthread_cond_signal()` after the `pthread_mutex_unlock()` if you want).

Answer (score 1):

caf's answer already says it all, but let me add a rationale for why locking is required here, since this can be a bit confusing at first.

Conceptually, a condition variable *signals* that a desired state was reached. It does not itself represent that state (in your case the state is represented by the `flag` variable instead). This is the reason why you still need an additional mutex: Concurrent changes to the condition variable itself are protected (e.g. you can notify from multiple threads at the same time), while changes to the data holding that state are *not* protected. This is why the condition variable is usually paired with a mutex: The condition variable signals a change in state while the mutex protects the state against races.

In some cases you do not need the mutex for the state (e.g. if your flag was an atomic variable). This usually happens when you mix lock-free data structures with condition variables. This is a smell. Condition variables are used to *wait* for a specific condition, they are always blocking by nature. With lock-free data structures you express the intent that you never want to block. Mixing the two usually indicates a flawed design in the first place.